# Shortcut for second moment of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I remember learning somewhere that a shortcut for the second moment of an exponential distribution is twice the mean, is this true?

Comment: The simplest approach for deriving moments of the exponential distribution is to start from $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\lambda^{-1}$. Taking the $n$th derivative with respect to $\lambda$ then gives $(-1)^n\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=(-1)^n n! \lambda^{-n-1}$, which rearranges to $E[x^n]=\lambda^{-n} n!$.

Comment: thank you, I saw that on wikipedia, but what I'm looking for is a shortcut for solving expected payout problems where losses on an insurance policy follow exp and there is a deductible, so I was wondering if once I find the expected payout, can I assume that the second moment is twice the mean, and with that I can easily find the variance?

Comment: For the case of $\lambda=1$, yes: $E[x^2]=2\lambda^{-2}=2,$ $E[x]=1\lambda^{-1}=1$. But otherwise no.

Comment: thank you and this would be the case for $\int_d^{\infty}(x-d)\cdot e^{-1x}dx$; that is $E[X]=\int_d^{\infty}S_x(x) dx$ and  $E[X^2]=2\cdot\int_d^{\infty}S_x(x) dx$?

Comment: Oh, perhaps I just developed some insight...Based on the formula you demonstrated, the second moment = twice the variance, which in the case of $\lambda=1$ only, would also be equivalent to twice the mean?

Comment: One more general way to put it is that $E[(x/\lambda)^2 ] = 2 E[(x/\lambda)]$. So the variance is twice the mean _up to scaling by the rate parameter_. (But equally well you can write $E[(x/\lambda)^n]=n!$.)